# How to open a file without a file chooser

Tags: file, filereader, jmenuitem

I have created a "Help" text file which I want to open when the user clicks "help" on my Java app without a file chooser being opened. I have saved the help file in the same place as my code

My attempt:

```
JTextArea open = new JTextArea ();
TabPane.add ("Help", open);
open.read (new FileReader (help.txt), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you read you want to display the content of the file to the textarea, right?

```
JTextArea open = new JTextArea();

BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("help.txt"));
    byte[] chars = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    try {
        while( (bytesRead = inStream.read(chars)) > -1){
            open.append(new String(chars, 0, bytesRead));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

you can do it like that then..

Comment: I don' necessarily want to display it in the text area just simply open the file but I am not sure of the code to call that specific file.

Comment: Hi, it reads your help.txt file and writes the result to the JTextArea.. this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("help.txt") accesses your file

Comment: thanks for some  reason it is'nt picking up help.txt even though it has been saved in the same location but i have worked out my own solution that works "fairly" well for now